# Different Layout of Webpage in IE 11, Windows 7

Tags: html, layout, internet-explorer-11

We have a webpage that is rendered differently on different PCs which run the same operating system in the same browser (Windows 7 Enterprise and Internet Explorer 11 with identical patch levels and identical configurations, as far as I can tell).
It does not seem to be a problem of any display settings or fonts. In fact, simple HTML buttons are rendered differently, as you can see here:

[image: one search button]

[image: another search button]

This also affects the placement of UI elements on the screen like alignment.

Any ideas about what could cause these differences?

Comment: Are you sure none of them are running in compatability mode, or that there is other settings (network, proxy, something like that) that prevent certain elements from working as they should (mainly CSS, in this case). I'm guessing that the bottom button is how it is supposed to look? Does any of the computers have "classic look" set up? Not Aero? (For Windows in general, not the browser)

Comment: The reason is the windows theme Aero versus classic, thanks! That was fast. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Aero vs Classic theme in Windows (due to the look of the buttons), as we found out in comments.